# How to prevent Minikube to redeploy, when resuming the VM with `minikube start`?

Tags: macos, kubernetes, deployment, virtualbox, minikube

## Suspending & resuming my virtual-machine does break the k8s deployment

When I suspend with `minikube stop` and then resume the Virtual Machine with `minikube start`, Minikube re-deploys my app from scratch.

I see this behaviour with newer versions of Minikube higher than *v1.18* (I run on *v1.19*).

---

## The setup:

- The *Kubernetes* deployment mounts a volume with the source code from my host machine, via `hostPath`.\
- Also I have a container of `initContainers` that setups the application.

Since the new *"redeploy behaviour on resume"* happens, the init-container **breaks my deploy, *if* I have work-in-progress code on my host machine**..

## The issue:

Now, if I have temporary/non-perfectly-running code, I cannot suspend the machine with unfinished work anymore, between working days; because every time I resume it **Minikube will try to deploy again but with broken code** and fail with an `Init:CrashLoopBackOff`.

## The workaround:

For now, each time I resume the machine I need to

1. stash/commit my WIP code
2. checkout the last commit with working deployment
3. run the deployment & wait for it to complete the initialization (minutes...)
4. checkout/stash-pop the code saved at point *1)*.

I can survive, but the workflow is terrible.

## How do I restore the old behaviour?

- *How do I make my deploys to stay untouched, as expected when suspending the VM, instead of being re-deployed every time I resume?*

Comment: Could you please describe what OS you're using? How exactly minikube is setup? Which driver does it use? What changed in your environment since you were able to `minikube stop and start` and it worked without issues for you?

Comment: Details are in the tags (MacOS & VirtualBox driver) and in the question. Minikube setup is the default (plus *ingress-addon*). In my environment I only upgraded to *1.19*, from *1.18*.

Comment: I want to make sure minikube uses a VritualBox and not `docker` or `HyperKit`. Do you start minikube with `minikube start --driver=virtualbox`? Also please check which driver is actually used in both or one of config files: `~/.minikube/profiles/minikube/config.json` and/or `~/.minikube/machines/minikube/config.json`

Comment: It's Virtualbox everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short words there are two ways to achieve what you want:

- On current versions of `minikube` and `virtualbox` you can use `save state` option in Virtual box directly.
- Move initContianer's code to a separate `job`.

**More details about minikube + virtual box**

I have an environment with minikube version 1.20, virtual box 6.1.22 (from yesterday) and MacOS. Also minikube driver is set to `virtualbox`.

First with `minikube` + `VirtualBox`. Different scenarios:

`minikube stop` does following:

> Stops a local Kubernetes cluster. This command stops the underlying VM
> or container, but keeps user data intact.

What happens is virtual machine where minikube is set up stops entirely. `minikube start` starts the VM and all processes in it. All containers are started as well, so if your pod has an init-container, it will run first anyway.

`minikube pause` pauses all processes and free up CPU resourses while memory will still be allocated. `minikube unpause` brings back CPU resources and continues executing containers from a state when they were paused.

Based on different scenarios I tried with `minikube` it's not achievable using only minikube commands. To avoid any state loss on your `minikube` environment due to host restart or necessity to stop a VM to get more resources, you can use `save state` feature in VirtualBox in UI or cli. Below what it does:

> **VBoxManage controlvm  savestate**: Saves the current state of the VM to disk and then stops the VM.

Virtual box creates something like a snapshot with all memory content within this snapshot. When virtual machine is restarted, Virtual box will restore the state of VM to the state when the VM was saved.

One more assumption is if this works the same way in v. 1.20 - this is expected behaviour and not a bug (otherwise it would've been fixed already)

**Init-container and jobs**

You may consider moving your init-container's code to a a separate `job` so you will avoid any issues with unintended pod restarts and braking your deployment in the main container.  Also it's advised to have init-container's code idempotent.
Here's a quote from official documentation:

> Because init containers can be restarted, retried, or re-executed,
> init container code should be idempotent. In particular, code that
> writes to files on `EmptyDirs` should be prepared for the possibility
> that an output file already exists.

This can be achieved by using `jobs` in Kubernetes which you can run manually when you need to do so.
To ensure following the workflow you can place a check for a `Job completion` or a specific file on a data volume to the deployment's pod init container to indicate that code is working, deployment will be fine.

Links with more information:

- [VirtualBox `save state`](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-controlvm)
- [initContainers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#detailed-behavior)
- [kubernetes jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/)

Comment: Not yet. I still wonder what made the behaviour of my cluster change: before I didn't experience this re-initialization. However, in the light of the good explanation from @moonkotte I think it makes more sense to move the operations from `initContainer` to a K8S `Job`, since I had an inexact understanding of the first one.