# Kubernetes Minikube removes all resources after shutting down

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

The Minikube cluster on my Debian system removes all resources which have been up and running after I run `minikube stop` or shutting down the system.

What could possibly be the reason? How can I persist it?

Kubernetes & Kubectl version 1.23.1.

Comment: Which driver are you using for minikube....if you are using `virtualbox` maybe you are experiencing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67691123/how-to-prevent-minikube-to-redeploy-when-resuming-the-vm-with-minikube-start

Comment: Do you receive any errors on ``minikube start``? At first glance, the problem seems to be similar to the issue raised [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/12655) - could you consider upgrading to 1.25.2 version?

Comment: @anarxz Yees, that was the problem, Thanks. you can post it as an answer so people can reach out to the solution easily.

Comment: @Faramarz Sure, posted, glad it helped you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting it as an answer: the issue with removing all deployed resources in Minikube cluster after `minikube stop` and system shutdown was raised [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/12655). It is currently fixed in the newest release, upgrading your Minikube installation to 1.25.2 version should solve it.